# Is it possible to play .m4a file using as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

I am developing a simple mp3 player for playing bulk number of audio files to play. The files are in .m4a format. Is it possible to play using as3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is an article about AAC and m4a files playing in actionscript using the NetStream class:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/hd_video_flash_player.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0

it's possible

Answer (score 1):

The below link show you flash supportable file formats.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/402/kb402701.html

Current version of flash doesn't support .m4a file. So u needs to convert it into mp3 file.

Comment: @Antony that is only correct if you want to import them into the IDE, but you can stream them.